# How to avoid using onClick on dynamically generated HTML elements (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My understanding is that I should usually avoid using onclick in HTML, since is better to keep separate HTML structure and JS logic.
However in this case, I have an application where the user can search for records and the results are displayed in divs dynamically generated from a php file using AJAX. In each div there is a button which when is clicked must perform a JS function and the function argument is the record unique id.

My point is: how could i select a dynamically created button with vanilla JS, since it does not exist when JS is loaded?

Comment: Make a delegate event listener on a pre-existing parent of the dynamic fields, catch the click event, determine if it is one of the elements you want to process for, and if so, perform your logic.

Comment: And this is why I am spoiled to death using jquery these days.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the click handler to the button, attach it to parent element of where the buttons will be placed. Then using `e.target`in the click handler you can reference the button that was clicked.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");

div.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute("id"))
});

div.innerHTML = "<button id='test' type='button'>Test</button>";
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idea of event bubbling

example:

```
addDiv = document.querySelector("#addDiv");
list = document.querySelector(".list");
//as an example the ID is this counter
let id = 1;
addDiv.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //this is a callback function that is going to add a new item to the DOM.
    //in your case this is being implemented in php.
    list.innerHTML += `<br><div id="${id}"><button>Click me to see my ID</button></div> <br>`;
    id++; //meaning id = id + 1
});

//now the answer of your question:

const getTheID = (e) => {
    //this function will be called (invoked) as soon as one of the elements inside the ".list" div has been clicked
    e = e || window.event; 
    // "e" is the event that happened, it is an object that have lots of other objects, you can use "console.log(e);" to see what is "e", I've added the || (meaning OR) window.event to
    //make sure that I'll catch the event, you can just rely on the e argument that is being passed by the browser automatically, but the better implementation is to add || window.event
    target = e.target || e.srcElement; 
    // e.target and e.srcElement are the same thing, but I usually e.srcElement to make sure that the safari browser users will have my application working with them.
    //the e.target or e.srcElement is the HTML element that has been clicked, you can see that by "console.log(target);".
    target = target.parentNode;
    console.log(target);
    //this is what's called event bubbling, this code target.parentNode will move up inside the DOM to the parent of the clicked element, so from <button> to <div id="?"> Now we can see the parent element of the button.
    //if you need you can target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode....etc as you need
    //see that in the console, use console.log(target); to see the output.
    const id = target.id;
    //here we're getting the ID of the element <div id="?">
    alert(id);
}

list.addEventListener("click", getTheID);
```